# Developer's error reports provide less information, where the user/phone previews a lot

Tags: android, crash, report

I regulary watch the crash/error reports of my users, if any.
This is what an error report looks like on a developers site of view (Don't scare, it's just partially German).

[image]

Finally, if it ever happened that you crashed an app you will know that you are providing much  more about you and your phone. Just for example the android version or the phone vendor.

The following 2 screenshots will illustrate how a crash report could look like (to the user):

[image]
[image]

Finally the question now is: Where do all this information get to?
Obviously to google and google will not provide it to the developers? That would be very, very sick. This kind of information (just like the android version or device (vendor)) would be very significant and interesting for the developers. If somehow, how can I see those?

Answer (score 0):

Look for [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) project - it collect all info, that you want. You can also do with errors whatever you want with providing your own [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: Both links are pretty useful, thanks! Do you have an idea why still so much information is collected but so less is previewed to the developer?

Comment: Because Google's programmers still didn't do it :)

Comment: Actually I wondering the same question and doing my own "error collector", not waiting official one.